# Module : - Share a global Variable Across Python Modules

Tags: python, module, global

I have created 3 file namely config.ipynb , update.ipynb and main.ipynb in same directory. I am using Jupyter notebook environment. The same code works fine with spyder environment under .py file format.

config.ipynb  :-  config module

```
 a = 0
b = "empty"
```

The module config.py stores global variables of a and b.

update.ipynb  :-   update module

```
import config
config.a = 10
config.b = "alphabet"
```

In update.py file, we import the config.py module and modify the values of a and b.

main.ipynb  :-

```
import config
import update
print(config.a)
print(config.b)
```

Similarly, in main.py file we import both config.py and update.py module. Finally, we print and test the values of global variables whether they are changed or not.

And I got this error :-

---

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

I am predicting that the answer will be

10

alphabet

Comment: Since the error is no module named config, it looks like the error lies in that you are not importing the module correctly, not necessarily an error with the variables